# multi-tenant and CodeFluent Entities design

Tags: sql, azure, codefluent

I'm designing a multi-tenant Azure application using CodeFluent Entities and plan to use Identity columns on all tables and a GUID for the Tenant ID. I have read this article > https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98118/composite-primary-key-in-multi-tenant-sql-server-database and also this article > [Best approach for multi-tenant primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450683/best-approach-for-multi-tenant-primary-keys). Has anyone done this using CodeFluent Entities?

Answer (score -1):

Using CodeFluent Entities, you can create a `Tenant` entity and create a composite key on all entities:

```
<Tenant>
    <Id key="true" typeName="guid" />
    <Name />
</Tenant>

<Entity>
    <Id key="true" typeName="int" persistenceIdentity="true" />
    <Tenant key="true" typeName="Tenant" />
    <OtherProperties />
</Entity>
```

If you have lots of entities, you can add the Tenant property using [an aspect](https://www.softfluent.com/documentation/AdvancedDesigning_Section.html).

Comment: I'm not sure I asked the right question. I understand about creating aspects ad have done this before. My question was (supposed to be) more about using CodeFluent Entities to generate SQL Azure multi-tenant structures. I know how to use CodeFluent to create schemas, I was looking for some more practical skills in terms of what's considered to be best practice regarding the use of composite keys in a multi-tenant environment and deploying continual database changes. Perhaps I should close this question and ask a better one?

Comment: My answer was about creating a composite key with CodeFluent Entities (`key` attribute). However, I think you are looking for best practices to design your database for a multi-tenant scenario. In this case, you should ask a new question (not related to CodeFluent Entities).